# How to apply back button to canvas in windows phone?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am trying to do an windows application. In the below image you can see that in Page1 where a button is there. When I select this button a canvas is opened. What I want to do is? When this canvas is opened in the Page1(right side) itself, if I select back button of windows phone. Then the canvas should disappear. How to do this kind of task?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can detect and cancel the navigation with the back button by overriding the `OnBackKeyPress` method and setting `e.Cancel` to true.

From there, it's just a matter of detecting whether the canvas is displayed.

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (EHeightCanvas.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        EHeightCanvas.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
}
```

Comment: For Select button i've written code in following format.  private void EHSelect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            EHeightCanvas.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed; }     Can u please give the answer in detail for back button with respect to my code.